# How do I group similar categories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, classification, text-classification

I have about 1200 tv show categories .. like Drama, News, Sports, Sports-non event, Drama Medical, Drama Crime.. etc

How do I use NLP so that I get groups such that Drama, Drama medical and Drama Crime group together and Sports, Sports-non event etc group together and so on... basically the end goal is to reduce the 1200 categories to very few broad categories.

Till now I have used bag of words to build a dictionary with 146 words..

Comment: Will all the categories of Drama start with 'Drama' and similar for other groups?

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How do I ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- (2) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Use a pre trained model to generate embeddings, and from there you can cluster the embeddings using a clustering algorithm like t-SNE or UMAP. I recommend `fasttext` or `spacy`, with `spacey` being the easiest to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for NLP packages there are a few modules you can check out, the first of which is:

### [SciKit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/)

It has a whole sea of classes and an orderly and easily understandable documentation, but doesn't use neural networks for text processing. There is also:

### [Natural Language Toolkit](https://www.nltk.org/)

It has a noticeable advantage of being the most developed and full-fleshed, but it's quite slow.

### [SpaCy](https://spacy.io/)

It's quite fast, but the speed comes at a price of not being as flexible as the other libraries I've mentioned. It has support for 7 languages, as of yet, I believe, but it might be enough for a starting point.

Still though, for what you aim to achieve with NLP, your best choice may be NLTK. There is a [great tutorial playlist from sentdex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLZvOKSCkxY&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDf2JswnfiGkliBInZnIC4HL). Good luck!